# Какая кодировка базы данных поддерживает таджикские буквы?

Tags: mysql

Какая кодировка поддерживает таджикские буквы вроде: (Қ,Ӣ,Ӯ,Ҳ,Ҷ i t.d.).
Если использовать `utf-8_general_ci`, то вместо них получаются знаки вопроса (???). 
Использую phpMyAdmin.
Если кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня в `utf8_general_ci` все приведённые символы отображаются.

Comment: Эту кодировку вы используете в описании таблицы, в описании полей или как кодировку клиента?

Answer (score 1):

```
Қ   &#1178;     қ   &#1179;
Ҳ   &#1202;     ҳ   &#1203;
Ҷ   &#1206;     ҷ   &#1207;
Ӣ   &#1250;     ӣ   &#1251;
Ғ   &#1170;     ғ   &#1171;
Ӯ   &#1262;     ӯ   &#1263;
```

Эти буквы поддерживает кодировка Unicode или UTF.
Решения некоторых затруднений с кодировкой можно найти [тут](http://php-myadmin.ru/learning/mysql-cir.html)